# How do I go about solving these two proofs?

Tags: proof-verification

**Show that the follow statement is true:**

If $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x^2+1=0$ then $x^4=\pi$

**Constructive proof:**

If $x,y$ $\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $x \lt y$, show that $\exists \ z\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $x\lt z\lt y$

Comment: Hint: Show the first part is always wrong. Therefore the statement is true.

Comment: I'm not sure what do do, I've only done proofs with even and odd numbers like x=2k and x=2k+1. I'm not sure how to get started for these two that involve all real numbers

Comment: @janny For the first one: Remember that if $p$ is false, then $p\Rightarrow q$ is always true. For the second one: take the average?

Answer (score 0):

-First one:

**Hint:**  $x^2 + 1 = 0 \Rightarrow x = \pm i$ and $p \to q$ is true if $p$ is false and $q$ is false.

-Second one:

**Hint:** If $x<y \in \mathbb{R}$ take $z = \frac{x + y}{2}$.

Comment: For number 1, what is i? an integer?

For number 2, since it's a constructive proof, can I say that y=2, x=0, z=1, so 0<1<2 =x<z<y

Comment: $i^2 = -1$ is a [complex number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number). In other words, in 1 there is no real number that its square is $-1$, the sentence is therefore false.

Comment: Take $z = \frac{2+0}{2}$, and you are absolutely correct.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just had a quick question. Why does z have to be (2+0)/2 instead of just "1"?

Comment: Because you want to show existence of $z$ for any $x<y \in \mathbb{R}$ you take, in particular, $x = 2$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad I could help.